# "Show in Finder" switches Desktops

Tags: macos, google-chrome, finder, osx-mavericks

Here's an odd problem I noticed with Chrome and the Finder. I'm new to OS X so I'm not really sure if this is a bug, or there is some setting that may fix it.

1. Select Assign To..None for the Finder app.
2. Open a Finder window on desktop 1.
3. Open a Chrome window on desktop 2.
4. Download a file in Chrome, and click on Show in Finder.

The new Finder window opens on Desktop 2, yet you are switched back to the Finder window in Desktop 1. This is confusing and requires a couple of clicks to get back to Desktop 2.

This behavior doesn't happen in iTunes when I click on Show in Finder there, so I don't know.

Comment: What settings are specified in the Mission Control preference pane in System Preferences?

Comment: If changing this option solved your problem, please provide an answer below to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecking "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for that application" in Mission Control System Preferences will fix the problem, but the side effects may not be desirable. Also, it seems this option is not consistent. Some Apple apps will automatically switch spaces anyway (Finder, iTunes),

Wouldn't mind a better answer.